# Where would I ask this question about city names?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I got a question about geography, why some city names remain the same in different languages and others not, where would I ask this?

Answer (score 8):

I think you don't need to ask it, because it has already been asked on [Linguistics Stack Exchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/):

[What are determinants of language specific city names](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/23173/9716)

Comment: ah thank you, I had difficulties finding something similar